# IMemoryCache in singleton service won't retain values after being added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I've created a Service for caching JWT tokens in ASP.NET, but when I go to retrieve a value after the key/value pair has been added, it returns null.  Here, the singleton get's added in program.cs with the interface and implementation, and the IMemoryCache should be given through dependency injection, (which it appears to be), but the memory cache simply doesn't retain values.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
```

```
    public class TokenService : ITokenService
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

        public TokenService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public Task<string> CreateUserToken(ulong userId, string tokenKey, List<Claim> claims, int hoursTillExpire = 4)
        {
            string token = CreateToken(tokenKey, claims, hoursTillExpire);
    
            Console.WriteLine(token); //displays token

            ICacheEntry cacheEntry = memoryCache.CreateEntry(userId);
            
            cacheEntry.SetValue(token);
            cacheEntry.SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(hoursTillExpire));

            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }

        public Task<bool> CompareUserToken(ulong userId, string token)
        {
            string? retrievedToken = memoryCache.Get<string>(userId);

            Console.WriteLine(retrievedToken); //shows nothing

            return Task.FromResult(token.Trim().Equals(retrievedToken?.Trim()));
        }

        private static string CreateToken(string tokenKey, List<Claim> claims, int hoursTillExpire)
        {
            SymmetricSecurityKey key = new(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenKey));

            SigningCredentials cred = new(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);

            JwtSecurityToken token = new(claims: claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(hoursTillExpire), signingCredentials: cred);

            string jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return jwtToken;
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface ITokenService
    {
        Task<string> CreateUserToken(ulong userId, string tokenKey, List<Claim> claims, int hoursTillExpire = 4);

        Task<bool> CompareUserToken(ulong userId, string token);
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your constructor, to make sure it only gets called once. How are you registering `IMemoryCache` ?

Comment: Another thing, why cache a JWT token?  The security and expiry is built into the token, and should be rejected by middleware if it has expired. A JWT token is like a security badge, it can be checked by anyone and rejected by them, there is no need to check in with the head of security to make sure it's OK, if the badge hasn't exipred and is valid, it's good to go.

Comment: I've added a breakpoint, and the constructor is only called once.  I was under the assumption that the ASP.NET framework would automatically create an IMemoryCache instance for dependency injection after I call `builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
`, is this wrong?

Comment: as for your second comment, I'm attempting to build a social media clone, and the user needs to be able to post under their own profile, and I assumed that using JWT tokens that are user specific in nature would be the best way

Comment: When a user logs in, you generate them a JWT token which is returned to the UI via a message body.   The UI then sends that JWT token with every GET/POST/PUT etc as the 'Authorize' header. The middleware will verify that the token is valid, and not expired, and then call the controller end point, with the `HttpContext.User` set to the claims in the token.   All of this is pretty much automatic in modern ASP.NET.  If you are reinventing any of this, then I suggest you read up on https://asp.net how to do it, it will save you loads of time and effort.

Comment: @Neil while your points are valid, they're off-topic to the behavior the OP is experiencing

Comment: @MatthewDolan are you using asp.net on .net framework or asp.net core on .net core? If you're using .net framework, how are you including IMemoryCache?

Comment: I'm currently using .net core, but what he did state solved my problem, but I'm still curious why it isn't working